# Css: change only first div

Tags: css

I have something like this:

```css
.first {
    background: yellow;    
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
 1
  <div class="second">
   2
    <div class="three">
     3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and i want to change color for first class so i want to see "1" for example with yellow background. Is it possible to make it in css?

Comment: All answers show how to overwrite the yellow background, but none tell you that if you are facing this issue, it is mainly because your HTML structure is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer mentioned cascade, however this isn't really a cascading issue. You've applied a `background` to `.first`, which is the parent element. Your nested, child elements (`.second` and `.three`) are not inheriting a `background-color`; they're just showing the `background-color` of `.first`.

Think about it like this:

```
|-----------------------
| FIRST                |
| |==================| |
| | SECOND           | |
| | |**************| | |
| | | THIRD        | | |
| | |**************| | |
| |==================| |
|----------------------|
```

In the beautiful ascii diagram above, `FIRST` has a `YELLOW` background color. All the children inside it (taking up space) are showing that background color because they have no background color.

#### Solution:

The way to avoid `.second` and `.third` from "inheriting" the color (again, it's actually just showing the background-color of `.first` - not inheriting) is to specify a `background-color` for those `divs` as provided by other answer. However, if you apply a `margin`, you'll notice an issue (the yellow will peek through on the edges where the margins have been applied). You'll also notice a similar issue with the `nested` `.three` element (showing `second`'s background color).

There is another option, which is to take `.second` and `.third` out of the DOM-flow, using `position: absolute`. If you're new to CSS, I don't recommend this without first understanding how `positioning` works (as there are other consequences, such as how `height` is calculated), however it will have the desired effect.

Anyway, good luck & happy learnings.

#### Demos:

#### Demo of `background-color` on `second` and `third`, but with `margin` applied.

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.first {
    background: yellow;    
}
.second, 
.three { 
    background-color: blue; 
    margin: 5px; 
}
.three {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
 1
  <div class="second">
   2
    <div class="three">
     3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Demo of removing from DOM flow using `position: absolute;`

```css
.first {
    background: yellow;
}
.second {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
 1<br />1<br />
  <div class="second">
   2
    <div class="three">
     3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too easy? I don't know what is allowed..

```css
.first {
    background: yellow;    
}
.second {
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
 1
  <div class="second">
   2
    <div class="three">
     3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets. It's called cascading because it cascades, it flows from the top to the bottom. Whatever style you apply to the top element will be flowed down to its child element, its grandchild, and so on, just like waterfall.

What you want to do is basically prevent the cascading to happen from first div to the second and third div. So what you can do is to apply a universal background-color (white) to all the div. After that (the order is important), you can apply a specific background-color to the first div. This will result in the first div having yellow background-color and the other div will override that with white background-color.

Here is the end result

```css
div {
  background-color: white;
}
div.first {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  1
  <div class="second">
    2
    <div class="three">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to partially color the `first` div so that you only cover the content you want (here the `1`). For this you can consider linear-gradient where you can easily adjust the size:

```css
.first {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, yellow) top/100% 1.2em no-repeat;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, pink, purple);
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  1
  <div class="second">
    2
    <div class="three">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="first" style="font-size:30px;">
  1
  <div class="second">
    2
    <div class="three">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You simply need to set the height of the gradient to be equal to the height of the linebox (defined by `line-height`) and you will color only one line.